# Send array with other inputs via AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
$scope.addVersion = function () {
          var appId = $scope.version.appid;
          var versionForm = {
              description: $scope.version.desc,
              versionNotes: [$scope.version.notes]
          };
          console.log(versionForm);
          $http({
              method: 'POST',
              data: versionForm,
              url: '//apps/' + appNumber + '/versions'
          }).then(function successCallback(response) {


          }, function errorCallback(response) {


          });
      }
```

Yes, this works. But actually, `$scope.version.notes` is must be array. Its HTML:

```
<textarea ng-model="version.notes" name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10" class="form-control"></textarea>
```

How can I fix it? Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what your `$scope.version.notes` might hold as a value?

Comment: I suppose if you really want `<textarea ng-model="version.notes"  ...`, then `version.notes` should be a plain string (possibly containing newlines...)

Answer (score 0):

```
      var versionForm = {
          description: $scope.version.desc,
          versionNotes: [].concat($scope.version.notes)
      };
```

Now versionNotes is an array.

Answer (score 0):

in textarea ng-model should be String. not an array